# How to preserve the order or terms in Orchard TaxonomyField

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I have a Content Part in Orchard, to which I added a Taxonomy Field and set it to allow multiple terms. When I save a content item, it looks like the terms are re-ordered in alphabetical order. But I would like to preserve the order in which they were authored in the field.

E.g. here is what I author in my Taxonomy field:

```
Contributors: [Sebastien Ros] [Bertrand Le Roy]
```

And here is what it turns into after saving:

```
Contributors: [Bertrand Le Roy] [Sebastien Ros]
```

Is there a way to prevent terms re-ordering? If this is by design, does anyone familiar with implementation know if this can be patched easily? Would it make sense to create a pull-request and contribute a patch to Orchard? I mean, would it be useful for other users, so that the fix has a chance to be included in core. (Otherwise, I would have to maintain a modified version of Orchard and have problems upgrading to new versions, which is undesirable of course).
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *never* count on the order in which the records are stored in the database. It is way too brittle, and has never been designed for this. If you need to have control over the order of terms, and have different orders depending on context, you need to use something else. The latest source code version of Vandelay.Industries has a projection filter that lets you drag and drop items in the order you want, for that specific projection.

Comment: Bertrand, I have not digged into details of implementation yet, but taxonomy fields might be stored as strings of respective term Ids. In that case, the order can be preserved naturally. If field's terms are stored as separate records (unlikely imho), I could add an orderNum property to that record and then maintain the value internally.

Comment: I see what you mean. For the field, yes, storage in the XML infoset. One problem I see is that there is more than one way to present the field, and only one has the potential to let you manipulate the order. Still, yes, it could be done. It could be an additional option.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the taxonomy section and look for the term itself, you will see a property call Weight which says..: 'If specified, it will be used to sort terms at the same level'. 

 That should do it.

Comment: This would always sort terms in the order defined in Taxonomy. What I need is to preserve the order used inside the field for a specific Content Item. The order may be different for same terms in different content items.

Comment: Then I would go the same route as @Bertrand mentions. <br>
Check the implementation of that Projection but it seems you already On the right path. <br>